# How to have multiple filesystems in a single gradle build?

Tags: gradle

First off, I'm a total noob with both Gradle and Groovy. :-)

I'm trying to port an existing project from an ant-based build to using Gradle. The problem I'm having is that my source code is stored in two different filesystems (both git repos). I've managed to get the Gradle subproject configuration working for modules that are in the same filesystem, but I can't seem to link subprojects across the two different filesystems. I have a need for projects in filesystem 'A' (my application repo) to depend on projects in filesystem 'B' (my library repo).

Is there any way to get Gradle to handle dependencies across fileystem boundaries?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say filesystem I'm guessing you mean they are in two different folders once checked out.

There's 2 ways to achieve what you want:

One is to build project B and publish the Jars into a 'repository' that project A has access to. I achieve this by copying the jars from projectB/build/libs to a projectA/lib folder and adding that lib folder as a repository in the project A's build file like so:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'lib'
    }
}
```

It's a little manual but it does the trick.

The other way is to use Gradle's new [Composite Build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) feature. It allows you to configure Project A to include Project B. This avoids the manual copying of jars. I haven't used this approach myself because it is very new so I can't vouch for how well it works.

Comment: I tried to use the Composite Build stuff, but it only seems to work for subprojects that are rooted at a common directory. In my case, I have two different directory roots (one for my app, and one for my library code). What I don't understand is why the distinction? Why can't I tell Gradle that I have a project in my library repo that my application repo depends on?

Comment: Hi Steve. I'm pretty sure that you can include a build from any directory. Are you sure you're not getting confused between a Composite Build and a multi-project build? Could you paste the contents of your build files or the command line arguments that you're using?

Comment: I think you're right that I'm mixing up the two different schemes. I'll try to take a deeper look into the Composite Build stuff and see what happens, One thing I did notice that may cause this to not work for me is that the docs state that there's no support for composite build in IntelliJ IDEA, and that's the IDE that we're using to do our work.

Comment: Could be your lucky day. IntelliJ 2016.3 just came out with support for Composite Builds. https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2016-3-gradle